# Wordpress: Can you assign the regular post categories to custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am just using custom post types for the first time today, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am using a custom post type that is predefined by a plugin. It looks like almost every Event Calendar plugin uses custom post types to set up an "Events" post type.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the normal categories I assign to my regular posts, to assign to the custom events posts.

For example, I have regional categories, like "Southeast" that I have been using for regular posts, but I would also like to be able to assign this category to event posts, so that when people look at the "Southeast" category archive, they can see the regular posts and the events posts associated with that category.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible, but depends on the plugin you are using to define your post type. So what is this plugin ?

Comment: I haven't settled on an event plugin for sure, but I will probably use **All-in-One Event Calendar**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code and instructions here:
http://wp.miragearts.com/allinone-event-calendar-events-blog-home-categories-tags/

I found with this code added to the functions.php, that if I create two categories (one for regular posts and one for the event custom posts) with the exact same name and slug, then it is basically the same as having one category.

I think this may be slowing my site down a bit, but it's really too early to tell if it will cause problems.

Here's a copy of the code for the functions.php:

```
// Add this to your theme's functions.php
function edit_my_query($query) {
  // Modify category and tag listings to include ai1ec events and all uses of the same term
  //  across event and post taxonomies
  //  ie live-music or arts whether they are event or post categories
  // also include ai1ec events in blog home and feeds
  if ( ( is_home() || is_feed() || is_category() || is_tag() ) 
          &&  empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    // The 'suppress_filters' test above keeps your menus from breaking
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type && $post_type[0] != 'post') {
      $post_type = $post_type;
    } else {
      $post_type = array('post','ai1ec_event'); // add custom post types here
    }
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    if (is_category() || is_tag()) {
    // Add custom taxonomies to category and tag pages
    if (is_category()) {
        $taxonomy1 = 'category';
        $taxonomy2 = 'events_categories';
      }
      if (is_tag()){
        $taxonomy1 = 'post_tag';
        $taxonomy2 = 'events_tags';
      }
      $queried_object = $query->get_queried_object();
      $slug = $queried_object->slug;
      $query->set('tax_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy1,  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $slug
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy2, 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $slug
        )
      ));
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'edit_my_query');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
add_action( 'init', 'myfuncxx'); function myfuncxx() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'custom_postttt_typee' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the WordPress function `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` Put the following into your theme's *functions.php* file:

```
function add_categories_to_events() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'event' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_to_events' );
```

Comment: I tried this, and got this error: **Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'add_category_to_events' was given in /homepages/0/d328057274/htdocs/cfsa-test/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405**
I also tried using this but changing 'events' to 'ai1ec-events' since I am using the All-in-One Events Calendar. Same error message.
I found this post on Wordpress.org and I am going to try to follow the directions: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-all-in-one-event-calendar-how-add-events-to-home-feed-categories-tagsh